# How to prove $f(x+iy)=\exp(\sin(y)+\sinh(y))$ is continuous in $\mathbb{C}$ but not differentiable in any point of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove $f(x+iy)=\exp(\sin(y)+\sinh(y))$ is continuous in $\mathbb{C}$ but not differentiable in any point of $\mathbb{C}$?

I can't find any relation to solve this problem. This is my first time in complex analysis course and i have no idea what to do.

Comment: Can you prove it's continuous?

Comment: What do you get with the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: Proving that it is continuous is practically the same as in the real case

Comment: Is it true that your definition is independent of $x$?  Or was that a mistake on your part?

Comment: If what you wrote is correct, consider writing $f(x + iy)$ as $f(x + iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$. Unless I am mistaken, $v(x,y)$ should end up being rather simple.

Comment: I think using the Cauchy-Riemann equations one might be able to solve the problem. Although I couldn't write in the form @Dair said.

Comment: Yes, @GEdgar, it is just $y$ dependent.

Comment: The function is real. Therefore, when you write it as $u+iv$ with $u,v$ real functions, then $v=0$.

Comment: In that case, the directional derivative in the horizontal direction is identically zero, so $0$ is the only possible value of $f'(x+iy)$,  Then just show the derivative in the $y$ direction is never $0$ to finish the proof that $f'$ never exists.